# Import/Export Contact Roles/Opportunity

Tags: opportunity, contact, opportunitycontactrole

We implemented a 3rd party solution in April that uses contact role on opportunities; however, we moved 1000's of records into opportunity that we did not add contact roles to (not realizing it would be necessary in the long run for reporting). Now I have to somehow locate all the opportunities that don't have contact roles and add contact roles to them.

Is there a way to export this data, fix it in a CSV, and use dataloader to update/upsert the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

> The object to import into is Opportunity Contact Role.  You will need
>   to mark the "Show all objects in Salesforce" checkbox to be able to
>   select Opportunity Contact Role.
>
> The .CSV file will need the following columns;
>
> 1. ContactID - ID of the Contact you are adding to the Opportunity Contact Roles related list
> 2. OpportunityID - ID of the Opportunity you are adding the Contact to
> 3. Role - Name of the role you are assigning to the Contact. This needs to be a value from the Role picklist
> 4. IsPrimary - This will mark the Primary checkbox on the Contact role.

It will be an insert to `OpportunityContactRole`.

Comment: Oh man, so getting them in will be easy once I identify what opportunities need them - but how do I identify the opportunities that don't have contact roles yet?

Comment: You could export all existing contact roles, build a pivot table on opportunity ID, and then export all opportunities to create a VLOOKUP in excel to get the count. Make sense?

Comment: Yes, Brian, I was just heading down that path in conversation with my developer. Thank you so much for your prompt response. You have been most helpful! Happy Holidays!

Comment: No worries, happy to help.